# How can I bind source of static resource in styles.xaml which is in Resources folders as Stringresources are in?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, static, styles

I tried to put static resource in styles.xaml which is in Resources folders as Stringresources are in.
i had binded static resoure as same way before in other pages, and it worked well.
and now exception coming up, and they say it can't find the source when i run this.

```xml
 <TextBlock 
    Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=AllRooms}}" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" 
    FontFamily="Noto Sans CJK KR Regular" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
 <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
    FontSize="16" FontFamily="Noto Sans CJK KR Regular" 
    FontWeight="Bold"
    Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=ByRoom}}" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: Please don't include tags in the title. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `styles.xaml` need to be included in `App.xaml`.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Folder_name_if_exists/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

After this, your styles would be available via the `StaticResource`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource AllRooms}"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" 
           FontFamily="Noto Sans CJK KR Regular"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
           Margin="0,0,10,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

In case you need to reference the `*.resx` file with your localization strings - you just need to include the containing namespace at the top of the file and then refer them via `{x:Static}`.

```
xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MyApp.NestedNamespace.Resources"
...

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static res.NameOfResourcesFile.NameOfResourceString}}"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" 
           FontFamily="Noto Sans CJK KR Regular"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
           Margin="0,0,10,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

#### UPDATE

Since your resources are static it is important to keep the declaration order from the most independent resources to the most dependent.

E.g.:
In case you have a dictionary with colors and brushes and another dictionary with styles that use those colors - their declaration order should look like the following:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Folder_name_if_exists/BrushesAndColors.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Folder_name_if_exists/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Declaring them in other ways will cause an exception.

Comment: Oh, thanks alot. after reading your answer, I found out that I putted Styles.xaml upon than Stringresources in App.xaml. I changed order and I solved the problem. thanks alot have a good day

Comment: @sk.han, updated my answer. Happy coding! :)